# Replacing an integer in an array of 100

Tags: java, arrays, replace, integer

I have to create a line of code that will replace the 7th number with the integer 7. I feel like I’m close but not quite there.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {        
    int [] numbers = new int [100]; 
    for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers [i] = -1;
        numbers [7] = 7;
    }
}
```

Comment: `numbers[7]` is the 8th number. For the 7th number, use `numbers[6]` .

Comment: If all you're trying to do is replace the 7th number, why are you looping through and replacing everything with `-1` ?

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in Java (and in many other programming languages) are zero-based. I.e., the first element is index 0, the second is index 1, etc, meaning that the seventh element is index 6:

```
numbers[6] = 7;
```

Additionally, you should note that there's no point in performing this same assignment over and over again in the loop. Just put it after the loop and you should be fine.